# Are there any truly 'unrecoverable' situations?

Tags: safety, spins, flight-school

I'm starting my quest to obtain a PPL this weekend. So I guess this question is contextualised around light aircraft like the Piper Tomahawk / Cessna, although it certainly would be interesting to get an answer that covers airliners too.

Baring a catastrophic technical failure, such as the wings falling off, a fire, or the horizontal stabiliser failing - ***is any [pilot caused] situation truly 'unrecoverable'?***

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/WKIk-dqml6U) of a student accidentally starting a spin. Naturally, he looked terrified, but the instructor took over and recovered quickly and easily. This made me wonder, is there anything a student can do that the instructor will not be able to recover from? (obviously smashing the plane into the tarmac on approach isn't really something that can be helped, so I'm only asking about events at altitude here).

Comment: The T-tail on the Traumahawk means it could "deep stall", where the elevator gets blanked by the wing and loses effectiveness, which is unusual in a trainer, however it's not unrecoverable, just more difficult. It's also pretty rare.

Comment: Think of risk this way Cloud.  Imagine the only vehicle you ever learned to operate was an airplane, and you were presented with learning the drive a car the first time.  You would probably observe the fact that all it takes to get killed in a car is to drift to the left or right say 6 feet.  You'd think, holy crap, I want to go back to my nice safe airplane that lets me wander all over the place without running into things.

Comment: There are a dozen scenarios in driving that will get you killed by inattention.  In flying about the only way to kill yourself on a nice day in an airplane with lots of gas aboard is to stall/spin in the circuit.

Comment: @JohnK Never mind the fact that it only takes drifting half a dozen feet to get yourself killed in a car; just look at those accident statistics!

Comment: a light plane called the AA-1 Yankee is said to have insufficient rudder authority to recover from a spin without very skilled hands on the controls- and its spin recovery characteristics are strongly asymmetric, meaning that in one direction it's supposed to be almost nonrecoverable from a spin. does anyone here know if this is true?

Comment: None of the Grummans were certified for spins as they tend to go flat.   Same with the Piper Cherokee.   However, even airplanes that aren't certified for spins are not unrecoverable right away; it just means you can't hold them in a spin because they will go flat after 4 or 5 or 6 rotations.  Just about any modern airplane will recover by itself from a spin entry within the 1st turn or two just be letting go of the controls.

Comment: You will see soon enough that the student in this video made a classical error of trying to recover the incipient spin with ailerons. This is _exactly_ what is taught [not to do] in stall/spin recovery lessons. Once you drill it in (likely making a few similar mistakes, with an instructor to help you), you won't be terrified.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One of the more common causes of crash and fatality is a *low altitude* stall-spin.  A spin, in a modern aircraft, isn't of itself deadly -- with many designs, all you have to do it let go of the controls, and the aircraft will unstall and let you simply fly out of the resulting spiral dive (if you don't wait too long and go past Vne, anyway).

If you get into a stall when low and slow, however, and due to control positions or pilot error initiate a spin, you're likely to hit the ground before you can recover.  Since ground impact in these cases is usually near vertical, nose down, and partially inverted, pilot survival is hardly assured.

Avoiding this kind of fatal mistake is why you practice stalls (with plenty of altitude under you) during flight training -- so you can recognize the conditions that bring on a stall, the aircraft behavior that announces it, and learn how to manage the airplane after the stall occurs to avoid, or intentionally initiate and recover from a spin.

This is (or ought to be) a part of the check ride before flying an unfamiliar type, as well.  Many older designs are less stall friendly than modern (say, post-1960) aircraft -- and if you learned to fly in a Cessna 152, you won't ever have experienced an unintended spin (because the type is difficult to spin even intentionally, and won't do it without large control inputs).  Stall a 1930s light plane at 100 feet, however, and you're likely to fail the "walk away" test.

Another situation that, once in, you can't get out of occurs in mountain flying.  If flying in a canyon under a ceiling (or near your aircraft's ceiling) you may find yourself without room to turn around, but with ground ahead rising into the overcast or faster than your aircraft can climb.  This leads to either "weather" or "Controlled Flight Into Terrain" being the listed cause of the accident, when in both cases it was genuinely pilot error -- this is a situation an aware pilot will avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately, my flight school only houses Terrorhawks. You know, the ones they designed to be easy to spin and won't recover unless you input the right controls. Naturally, I'm apprehensive about my lessons, so I'm just trying to figure out how to make sure I never stall or spin in the first place. I certainly don't fancy practicing them. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Flight schools use Tomahawks because it's very difficult to teach spin avoidance and recovery in a trainer that's effectively spin-proof.  You *need* to learn how to enter and recover from a spin, as well as how to manage a stall in an airplane that will spin.  Otherwise, regardless of requirements to learn to spin and recover to get your license, you'll be in serious trouble the first time something goes badly in an aircraft that isn't spin-proof.

Comment: But I would rather just stick to spin-proof planes! I'm a baby! :p

Comment: I might suggest that you can learn useful things about stalls, spins, and spin recovery by flying a radio control "advanced trainer" type.  These models fly very much like light aircraft -- but if you crash, you just have to repair or replace a model airframe, nobody gets hurt.

Comment: There's no such thing as spin-proof. Don't worry about it unduly, learn the lessons and you'll be fine. Get in the habit of watching your airspeed and balance like a hawk when climbing or on approach, and taking positive action quickly if airspeed gets low or your balance is out. Don't get fixated on it, just make sure to come back to it every few seconds.

Comment: Also, ensure your center of mass is where it belongs.  Tail heavy airplanes are insanely prone to stall, moreso since you lose pitch authority as the aircraft noses up and slows, and an aft CG is listed as cause of accidents fairly frequently.  Not just before takeoff; unsecured luggage has killed people.

Comment: Of course you're afraid of stalls & spins, @Cloud, you're supposed to be! But, as stated in the 3rd paragraph, that's why they have you practice it - so you know the signs when one begins to happen and you can take the proper corrective action _before_ you end up dead. I'm pretty sure this won't be in your first lesson, either.

Comment: Do students still need to demonstrate recovering from a spin? I thought the standard had changed to just have it demonstrated to them.

Comment: @CrossRoads In the US, Spins are not even demonstrated... They don't even go full-stall anymore, recovery is initiated at the first *sign* of a spin (if you get the horn, you've gone too far). I believe Cloud is in the UK though, and I'm not sure how their curriculum works.

Comment: @RonBeyer The school tell me that spin and stall recovery is practised at altitude as you approach your first solo. I live in a mountainous area and many Tomahawks have crashed around here.

Comment: The UK syllabus for spin training is for incipient spins only (1st quarter turn of the spin). I think Canada is one of the few places that teaches full spins, although if you are training in an airplane not certified for spins, it can also be limited to incipient spins.

Comment: @Cloud Light plane crashes in mountainous areas are most often due to either weather (pop-up storm or clouds closing in while flying in a canyon) or CFIT (flying so far up a canyon there isn't room to turn around, but terrain climbing faster than the airplane can climb, for instance).

Comment: @ZeissIkon I think the OP may be talking about "attitudes" rather than "situations," but since he did say situations you might add your last comment to your answer. That sounds like an unrecoverable situation to me if you fly into a place where you can neither turn nor climb out of.

Comment: @TomMcW Good suggestion.  Editing.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to make an assumption that solo student flights are in scope here, in which case I would say that flight into IMC (Instrument Meteorological Conditions) would quite often be unrecoverable. Instrument flight is a completely different discipline, without training it takes mere moments to become disoriented and lose control. If you do ever get into IMC glue your eyes on your attitude indicator and do a gentle 180 degree turn to exit while maintaining altitude, do not trust your inner ear!

Another potentially unrecoverable situation would be to fly under steadily lowering cloud until it puts you into a situation where landing safely is not possible. Being trapped between overcast and rising terrain with no landing spots will not end well. Scud-running is just stupid with all the high tension lines and cell towers that have sprung out of the ground.

These are preventable situations. Sometimes people succumb to get-there-itis or peer pressure and convince themselves the clouds are thin, or they're bound to raise in a bit, after all the TAF says so. Good flight planning and sticking to your limits will keep you out of that kind of trouble.

Comment: Lowering ceiling isn't the only way to get caught in a bad situation. I've had a training flight that started out quite okay, but the clouds were ominously closing in on us from the sides. (Forecast was for conditions to go from moderate to better; reality was from moderate to worse.) At one point I just decided that it was starting to cut it a bit too close for my comfort, and simply told the instructor that we're heading back to the airport and getting down on the ground. In that case the ceiling was high enough that we could in principle had flown below the clouds, but with little margin.

Comment: Well done recognizing the situation and taking positive action @αCVn. I've had inadvertent entry into IMC myself, 8000 ft over the English Channel on my way to France, realized that the TAFs were a superb work of fiction. I have an instrument rating so it wasn't life threatening.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, an airplane being operated within its published limits won't be able to get into a truly unrecoverable situation. (I'm specifically excluding the case where a recovery is theoretically possible, but you don't have enough altitude to execute the procedure before you hit something -- presumably you're already aware that you have less margin for error when you're operating at low altitude.)  However, when you don't operate within approved limits, you can get into truly unfixable trouble.

For example, a flat spin is often unrecoverable.  Most airplanes cannot enter a flat spin while properly loaded, but it's possible for it to happen if the plane's center of gravity is aft of the approved limits.

Depending on your definition of "pilot-caused", ice accumulation  might also qualify.  In addition to simply preventing the wings from generating enough lift, icing can cause a tail plane stall, which may or may not be recoverable.

There are probably others, but the point here is that the plane is designed to behave itself when operated as directed.  If you go outside of those limits, you no longer have any guarantee about what to expect.

Answer (score 6):

Let me go out somewhat on a limb here.

> student [...] looked terrified

**I'd say that any time you, the pilot, loses composure and/or situational awareness, that can very easily turn a normally recoverable situation into an unrecoverable one.**

If you, the pilot, panic, then it's going to become a lot more difficult to fly the airplane safely.

That's one major reason why so much time in training is spent on emergency procedures, including the emergency checklist recitement before take-off, along with the pre-takeoff mentally going through what you'll do if something goes wrong at various points during the take-off and climb-out.

I've had a few pretty good scares myself. One relevant here was when, early during climbout from an uncontrolled airport, one wing probably entered a bit of a downdraft and all of a sudden the airplane was banked something like 20-30 degrees to the side. I quickly wrestled the plane back to about level, almost without thinking, and flew through it, but I don't doubt that if I had lost my composure, it could very easily have led to a crash because there was very little altitude for recovery.

Get-there-itis has already been mentioned, and can be a major factor. Don't be married to the idea of making a take-off, or for that matter to that approach you're flying. A controlled landing, even an outfield landing, is always better than a crash. Aborting on the ground (below decision speed, which isn't much of an issue in small airplanes) and going around on approach, along with more generally buying yourself some margin (by for example climbing or turning), is *always* an option, even in controlled airspace.

Answer (score 5):

A stall at low altitude would be one unrecoverable situation, but hopefully the instructor would be alert enough to intervene in time to prevent this occurring. Spins are normally recoverable in light aircraft, but this is not always so in fast jets. The F84F Thunderstreak was one example of an early jet fighter in which a spin was considered unrecoverable.

Comment: Is it even possible to spin a large jet, i.e. a 737?

Comment: Few if any commercial aircraft designed after about 1960 will spin unintentionally, but many can be intentionally spun.  Flaps zero, throttle idle, full aft yoke, full rudder, and she'll spin, at least a bit.  Same way you spin a "spin proof" trainer.

Comment: In a Cirrus, spins are also considered "unrecoverable". The Cirrus manual's procedure for "recovering" from a spin is to pull the CAPS lever.

Comment: @ZeissIkon  I think "spin proof" means the aircraft will essentially fly itself out of a spin if you just let go, not that you can't make it go in circles if you really try.

Comment: @RonBeyer the Cirrus has that ridiculous spin procedure because the FAA allowed them to skip spin testing if the parachute was made the recovery procedure.  The Cirrus has more or less "unknown" spin behavior.  However, most airplanes with "unrecoverable" spin characteristics require full development of the spin to get to the unrecoverable part; several turns at least.  I will bet dollars to donuts that a Cirrus will pop out of a spin if recovery is started within the first turn or two like any other plane.  The idea of pulling a parachute at 6000 ft at the beginning of a spin is nuts to me.

Comment: @JohnK Yeah I'm aware that Cirrus petitioned the FAA to avoid spin testing because of the CAPS system. I'm sure that given enough altitude you can pull out even in a Cirrus. It is nuts to me too, however the US does not teach spin recovery training and the Cirrus has a maximum speed (and minimum altitude) at which the CAPS is effective, so if you don't "get it" by the time you exceed CAPS speed, you're screwed. I'm actually disappointed they don't teach spins anymore, and even more disappointed they don't teach full-stall recovery anymore (in the US).

Comment: All this talk about Cirrus. I just want to train in one of those now :D What could go wrong?

Comment: @RonBeyer IN the UK, IIRC the logic for not requiring spin training for a basic pilot's licence was that there were more accidents and incidents involving intentional spins during training, than from unintentional spins after training. As for stalls, arguably you should *never* get into a full stall except intentionally, but that assumes that pilots are always aware of what is going on, which is demonstrably not true.

Comment: "What could go wrong?" -- most of the same things that could go wrong in a Tomahawk.  Stall at 100 feet after takeoff, and the CAPS won't save you -- no time for the parachute to open before you become part of a pile of shattered composite soaked in avgas.

Comment: Regarding some modern aircraft with a spin recovery procedure like deploying parachute, I think one reason is that this lets you have a smaller fin and rudder what means less drag and a higher top speed - good for sales.  Another reason, is it only takes a couple of minutes to demo the parachute whereas it takes quite a while to demonstrate a lot of conventional spin recoveries.  Personally, I prefer a a big fin and rudder and relying on myself to recover from the spin to relying on the execs of a mfr who flim-flammed the FAA.

Comment: @RonBeyer The U.S. doesn't teach full-stall recovery? My instructor had me stall and recover literally the first time I ever flew an airplane in the U.S. And my instructor had me demonstrate it several more times on subsequent flights. This has been a few years, but not _that_ many (maybe 6?)

Comment: @reirab They do not teach it anymore as per the new airmen certification standards, adopted in 2017. If you've done (or are going to do) a BFR in the US, these will be the standards you are tested to (aka, no full stall). They are not required to teach it, but I think a lot of instructors still do. The point is that the student is supposed to recover at the first sign of a stall (buffet, not the horn), not wait until a stall develops.

Comment: @Flynn, they don't 'demo the parachute': you can't fold it back that quickly, and the airframe is generally considered a write-off after parachute landing. But they teach the procedure, of course.

Comment: @Zeus There is a repack cost for the parachute, so I think in some situations, the airframe is not a write-off.

Comment: @Cloud, I guess this is more for accidental deployment on the ground, or perhaps a procedure required after some time. _Normally_, the airframe should be assumed a write-off. As it happens, we have a [special question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1121/13666) about that. I heard this was a significant reason why SR-22 didn't enjoy the best safety record as Cirrus hoped: pilots are reluctant to pull the handle. It took a change in insurance T&C such that now it is effectively the 'get a new airplane' handle :)

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are all very correct, but I do want to emphasize a key philosophical element here.  When you ask *is any [pilot caused] situation truly 'unrecoverable'*, it's important to remember that there is always a point of no return.

There are hundreds of accidents where the pilot took the aircraft out of a situation that was otherwise safe, and ended up crashing the aircraft... sometimes recognizing his/her error just in time to understand what went wrong without time to fix.  Look at recent mishaps with the Thunderbirds, where they entered an aerobatic maneuver at the wrong altitude.  Or look at the Air France flight that went down off Brazil, where they brought the aircraft into a dive that was unrecoverable when recognized.

At any moment, the aircraft *could* be unrecoverable if your situational awareness is low and you react incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Agree 100% with 'a CVn'. Plus there is the oft missed teaching of Spatial Disorientation, is the one killer in aviation that is often 'unrecoverable'. So many accidents have happened under this cause, and have killed a lot of pilots, passengers, as well as complete families. As mentioned above, 'scud running' is dangerous, especially in mountainous terrain, where you may not have enough room to turn around and get out - and crash into a mountainside trying to.  Google 178 seconds to live. There are several ominous videos out there describing this situation that could save your life if one pays attention to the precursors.  The AOPA has several very good instructional videos on this subject as well.